# "Ночь, в которой" или "в которую"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Ночь, в которую умерла магия" или "Ночь, в которой умерла магия"? Как вернее? Пока склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, правильный вариант: *Ночь, в которую умерла магия* (что значит: *ночь, **когда** умерла магия*).

Выражение *Ночь, в которой умерла магия* означает, что магия умерла *в ночи* (словно магия растворилась в ночи).